# How can I create/post an Open Graph object instance/record with a custom property?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
var hashid = 'abc123'; 
var title = 'Awesome Widget';
FB.api( // creating the widget object instance/record
  'me/objects/myapp:widget',
  'post',
  {
    object: JSON.stringify({
      'app_id': <obfuscated>,
      'url': 'http://example.com/' + hashid, // maps to og:url
      'title': 'widget',  // maps to og:title
      'myapp:real_title': title,  // maps to nothing right now!  No bueno!
      'image': { // maps to og:image
        'url': 'http://example.com/images/' + hashid  
      },
      'description': 'Man, this widget is awesome!' // maps to og:description
    })
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

Yes, I've already created the custom "widget" object and the custom "real_title" property.  The object is being created, but the "real_title" property is not included:

[image: no bueno]

Do I need to specify a special syntax in the object instance/record for each property (`og:title`, etc.)?

P.S.

I want `og:title` to be simply "widget" because I want to create user stories in a specific way.  Hence, the need to also specify `real_title`.

P.S.S.

Am I actually creating an object instance, object record, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#properties):

> Standard object properties are added to the top-level of the JSON
>   object that you pass into your call to create an object.
>
> Any property that's not a standard object property should be included
>   as a data: {...} element on the JSON object you pass in when creating
>   an object. Here's an example of a custom mountain type that includes
>   an elevation custom property;

```
{
  title: 'Mt. Rainier', 
  type: 'myapp:mountain',
  image: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mount_Rainier_5917s.JPG', 
  url: 'https://url.to.your.app/example/mountains/Mt-Rainier',
  description: 'Classic cold war technothriller',
  data: {
    elevation: 14411
  }
}
```

> This format is the same as what an object looks like when it's read
>   back from the database via the Graph API.

In short, you need to be doing the following:

```
var hashid = 'abc123'; 
var title = 'Awesome Widget';
FB.api( // creating the widget object instance/record
  'me/objects/myapp:widget',
  'post',
  {
    object: JSON.stringify({
      'app_id': <obfuscated>,
      'url': 'http://example.com/' + hashid, // maps to og:url
      'title': 'widget',  // maps to og:title
      'image': { // maps to og:image
        'url': 'http://example.com/images/' + hashid  
      },
      'description': 'Man, this widget is awesome!', // maps to og:description
      'data': {
        'real_title': title // maps to myapp:real_title
      }
    })
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

Comment: Perhaps, if I had made `real_title` a required property, the API response might have given some clues about this.  Not sure though.